# I can't import a module from a different directory?

Tags: python, module, python-import

My directory looks like this:

```
project/
     src/
          __init__.py
          pdf_analysis_tools.py
     tests/
          test.py
```

pdf_analysis_tools contains the transcribe() function.

test.py contains

```
from ..src.pdf_analysis_tools import transcribe

print(transcribe("data\local-directory\1001\1001.0001.pdf"))
```

Or one of the many other things I have tried to get this import. In the current configuration, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

same shit if try to  import src or import ..src or import ..src.pdf_analysis_tools or import src.pdf_analysis_tools

Im at my wits end my dudes

Comment: What test module are you trying to use?

Answer (score 0):

```py
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join('..', 'src')))
from pdf_analysis_tools import transcribe

print(transcribe("data\local-directory\1001\1001.0001.pdf"))
```

Comment: isnt this kind of a dirty hack? shouldnt there be a cleaner way to import?

Comment: It would be helpful if you edited your question to provide some context and explanation of how this code answers the question.

Comment: It doesnt work, I just get no module named pdf_analysis_tools